# Как получить и тут же удалить содержимое ячейки MySQL из Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql, sql

Есть БД `MySQL` и `Python3` программа, работающая с этой БД. Так же есть некоторая последовательность чисел, которая должна быть неким образом записана в БД (*я предполагаю, что существует возможность того, что между получением чисел, и их обработкой программа может быть перезапущена/закрыта, поэтому они хранятся в БД*).

В программе есть 2 функции, одна из которых периодически дописывает новое число в последовательность, другая же должна в определенный момент обработать всю записанную на данный момент последовательность, но лишь 1 раз, поэтому я хочу тут же удалить последовательность из БД.

Пытаюсь понять как это оформить, чтобы превентивно устранить вероятность варианта, когда сначала `функция2` получает, потом `функция1` дописывает туда число, и потом удаляется содержимое, т.е. что одно или более чисел, дописанных в конец последовательности будет утеряно.

Как будет правильнее - отправить из Python команды `SELECT` и `UPDATE SET NULL` в `MySQL` так, чтобы `MySQL` выполнил их сразу подряд, отложив выполнение других команд с ячейкой на после? Если это возможно? Или это лучше "во избежание" оформлять полноценной таблицей, с `Index` и удалением по конкретным `Index` при том, что когда чего то добавляется у него уникальный еще больший `Index`? Не хотелось бы, как бы целая таблица против 1 ячейки...

Как я себе это, примерно, понимаю (я это пока что не тестировал, возможность будет сильно позже, но это же не мешает обдумывать?). Возможно ли лучше?

```
update_query = """
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE
    row = 'what_I_need'

UPDATE
    table
SET
    column = NULL
WHERE
    row = 'what_I_need'
"""

...

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for result in cursor.execute(update_query, my_string):
                    print(my_string)
```

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, то есть два процесса. Первый закидывает в БД по одному числу. Второй должен взять на обработку сразу все имеющиеся в данный момент необработанные числа. Если во время этой обработки первый процесс запишет ещё одно число - оно должно не обрабатываться в этой обработке, а остаться в таблице и начать серию чисел, которая будет обработана при следующей обработке. Верно?

Comment: В 2 словах верно, да. Хотя мне глобально безразлично будет оно обрабатываться в этот раз или нет, я просто не хочу чтобы оно обработалось 2 раза, или не обработалось совсем (потерялось). Меня волнует, что команда на добавление может проскочить между `SELECT` (оно не попадет в 1ю выборку), и `UPDATE SET NULL` (оно удалиться и так же не попадет и во вторую выборку).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможная реализация.

Создаём таблицу для хранения чисел:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
  one_number INT,
  processing ENUM ('not processed', 'processing', processed) DEFAULT 'not processed'
);
```

Процесс 1 записывает в таблицу данные запросами типа:

```
INSERT INTO numbers (one_number) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO numbers (one_number) VALUES (2), (3);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (4, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO numbers (one_number) SELECT some_number FROM another_table;
```

Процесс 2 сначала помечает записи на обработку

```
UPDATE numbers SET processing = 'processing' WHERE processing = 'not processed';
```

затем обрабатывает, после чего помечает обработанные записи

```
UPDATE numbers SET processing = 'processed' WHERE processing = 'processing';
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/xD86r6CT) с пояснениями.

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит очень красиво =)